# Rotate game Player

Tags: javascript, jquery, game-physics

Help me please. I create gamePlayer. He can move into Up Down Right Left. He can rotate, but not right. Please, my code.

```
if (event.key == 'ArrowRight'){
        Player.direction.transform = 0;
    };
    if (event.key == 'ArrowLeft') {
        Player.direction.transform = 180;
    };
    if (event.key == 'ArrowDown'){
        Player.direction.transform = 90;
    };
    if (event.key == 'ArrowUp'){
        Player.direction.transform = -90;
    };
```

If you will see I have a problem with rotate from position "ArrowLeft" to position "ArrowUp", it's angle 270deg. Maybe I need use another logic way, don't use rotate and use coordinate system (X, Y) ???

Comment: Are you using Unity 3D?

Comment: Where is the relation to jQuery in this question?

Comment: Where is the relation to game physics in this question?

Comment: Um `270deg % 360deg` is actually `90deg` so everything is fine? It does not matter if you turn left by 90 degrees or right by 270degrees